How do I make my circuit diagram look better? Or is it wrong?
This is my first time making a circuit diagram with this many components. Any advice on how I can make it more organized or look better? The wiring looks wire to me but I'm not sure if it looks wrong.

Specifically, the LEDs look really weird bc I had to make a black box for a part that's just a hole in the PCB. I tried to use the schematic linked with the PCB, but I think I need to make the JC2 and JC3 in series with their own components, like JC1.  Is that the wrong way to do it?

Does my G1 or G2 look weird like that?


I'm using a protoshield v2 (bare PCB) on an Arduino uno r3!


The layout is not terrible, but I'm not sure about the design intent. Isn't the JQC relay shorting the 5V supply as shown, for starters? If this is going to be a PCB you'd want connectors where you are showing batteries.

Make sure you connect those Arduino shields to GND, and the protoshield needs a VIN as well.

Is pin 6 of the JQC relay connected to anything at all? I also would use a diode over the relay to avoid burning up the contacts.

It's not bad! Can be even better. I like a convention of signals flowing left to right, power flowing top to bottom.
For signals there may be an exception - if there are clear physical sides, for me it overrides the left to right rule. So if i make an interface board, there will be port A and port B, with all A inputs and outputs on the left side and so on.
So... LED - power, make it flow down.
Power - use global nets. G2 is a battery? Make it vertical, put a global net for + and -.

The signal flow isn't bad, but there are several errors.
The G2 anode never connects to anything.
The G1 anode never connects to anything.
The upper relay (Reference Designators - !) pin functions do not match the graphic.
The upper relay places a dead short to GND on the 5 V.
